# ps -ef vs ps aux

Tags: process

What is the difference between

```
ps -ef | grep thin
```

and

```
ps aux | grep thin
```

As per the output there is a variation but i'm not clear what are the things being listed.

Comment: Here's a good explanation: http://superuser.com/questions/117913/ps-aux-output-meaning

Comment: @Rinzwind thanx

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Both list all processes of all users. In that aspect `-e` and `ax` are completely equivalent.

Where they differ is output format specifier, `-f` is "full", while `u` is "user-oriented". The displayed columns are different:

- columns for `ps -f`

`UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD`

- columns for `ps u`

`USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND`

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by a definition for each of the column headers, or at least for the relatively non-obvious ones like "C" and "VSZ."

Answer (score 19):

There are no differences in the output because the meanings are the same.

The difference between `ps -ef` and `ps aux` is due to historical divergences between POSIX  and BSD systems. At the beginning, POSIX accepted the `-ef` while the BSD accepted only the `aux` form.

Today, both systems accept the two forms.

Comment: Technically he is asking WHAT those differences are ;)